# Angular material : layout responsive

Tags: html, angularjs, flexbox, material-design, angular-material

i'm trying to make my contents inline center but not working any idea please ?

**DEMO:**

http://jsbin.com/xihaqonude/edit?html,output

Comment: What do you mean by "inline center"?

Comment: @camden_kid i want be my content center look demo for understing

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/xerayiguce/1/edit?html,output

Believe you are looking for

```
<div layout-align="start center" layout="column">
```

but if you want the contents to still have a flush left edge need an extra container around them otherwise the text gets centered.